# Find from where the data comes to "the_content()" function

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This might look an ordinary question though I'm stuck in it. I'm new to the wordpress. I've bought a wordpress theme and I'm trying to edit some pages as I want. Now I want to edit the default post page where I've already started editing the "single.php" and "post-format.php" files. I want to know from where or how "the_content()" function gets data?

Since I want some html part of the page to be removed though that html part comes through a "the_content" function. Therefore, I'm unable to remove that part without getting rid of "the_content" function. But I can't get rid of "the_content" function because the very same function calls some important part too.

Hope you guys can help!

Answer (score 0):

**From Where**

1. As a function `get_the_content()` retrieve the post content (Generally Used in a Loop) from database and prints on the frontend.
2. And again `the_content()` as filter controls how you show the post content.

**How**

Dead simple answer by WordPress API. You need to understand WordPress [Database_API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_API) for in-depth understanding.

*Frequently Used by*

```
wp-includes/plugin.php: apply_filters()
wp-includes/post-template.php: get_the_content()
wp-includes/post-template.php: the_content
```

**Usage Case: (from [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page))**

- post_password_required()
- get_the_password_form() if post_password_required() fails
- wp_kses_no_null() while processing the tag.
- balanceTags()
- get_permalink()
- global: $id, $post ,$more, $page, $pagesm, $multipage, $preview, $pagenow

**Ref:**
 - [Filter `the_content()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)  | [Function`the_content()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/)

*Optional: Offline WP Codex Docs Search/Browser for [Windows](https://zealdocs.org/)/[OSx](https://kapeli.com/dash)*